# How assign properties to nested object?

Tags: groovy

I have a filter loop that compares list items to nested object items:

**processArticlesNumbers**:

```
processArticlesNumbers = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

**articlesMap**:

```
[Business_Unit1: 
    [Supplier1: 
        ["2", "5", "8"],
    Supplier2: 
        ["2", "5", "8"]
    ],
 Business_Unit2: 
    [Supplier3: 
        ["2", "5", "8"],
    Supplier4: 
        ["2", "5", "8"]
    ],
]
```

I want to filter out the values and assign values that don't match to the new object with the same structure (`expiredAndNewArticlesMap`).

Currently, I'm receiving the following error:

> expiredAndNewArticlesMap.$({ -> ... }).$({ -> ... })" is a method call
>   expression, but it should be a variable expression

```
def articlesMap = checkNewAndExpiredArticles()
def expiredAndNewArticlesMap = [:]


articlesMap.each { businessUnit, articlesInfo ->
    articlesInfo.each { supplier, supplierArticles ->
        supplierArticles.each { articleNumber ->
            println articleNumber
            if (!processArticlesNumbers.contains(articleNumber)) {
                if (expiredAndNewArticlesMap.${businessUnit}){
                    if (expiredAndNewArticlesMap.${businessUnit}.${supplier}) {
                        expiredAndNewArticlesMap.${businessUnit}.${supplier}.add(articleNumber)
                    } else {
                            def list = []
// ERROR appears here 

                       expiredAndNewArticlesMap.${businessUnit}.${supplier} = list
                        expiredAndNewArticlesMap.${businessUnit}.${supplier}.add(articleNumber)
                    }
                } else {
                    expiredAndNewArticlesMap.${businessUnit} = [supplier: []]
                    expiredAndNewArticlesMap.${businessUnit}.${supplier}.add(articleNumber)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I assign values to a nested object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access an arbitrary property from a string name, you need to use a GString like:

```
expiredAndNewArticlesMap."${businessUnit}"
```

and

```
expiredAndNewArticlesMap."${businessUnit}"."${supplier}"
```

You can also access the map via key in a much more clear manner:

```
expiredAndNewArticlesMap[businessUnit]
```

And when you want to assign a particular key from a variable containing a string you need to wrap it in parenthesis:

```
expiredAndNewArticlesMap."${businessUnit}" = [(supplier): []]
```

Comment: Using property access with Gstrings is a tad convoluted.  Just use `[x]`.